# Sporadic response from div tags

Tags: html, css

I am getting sporadic behavior from a mobile app web page which displays appointments. The actual appointments are dynamically created div tags div tags of the proper length, width and positioned within a containing block which has overflow: auto; position: relative, so that I can calculate their position on the page relative to the time scheduled. By clicking on a particular appointment box, certain details of that appointment are displayed.

Now, everything is rendered fine and clicking on an appointment works for all appointments that appear on approximately the top 2/3 of the containing block but those in the lower portion give no response when clicked UNLESS you scroll the display (even the slightest movement will do the trick) and then those appointments that wouldn't respond before now work perfectly.

Any clue as to where I should start looking?

Here is some code which is an excerpt of a PHP page used in an Ajax call to display the page (hence, the echo statements):

```
$ht = screen_useable_height(310, 0);
echo '<div id="appointments" style="width:'.screen_useable_width(57, 600).'px;height:'.$ht.'px">';
// Create the Time of Day column from the DRAW TABLE ARRAY LOAD FROM TH DATA BASE       
echo '<table align="left" border="0" cellspacing="0">';
    $rnddiv = "-1";
    $rndx = "x";
    for ($i=0; $i<$timecnt; $i++) {
        // check if div header
        $flag = 0;
        for($j = 0; $j<$drawcnt; $j++) {
            if($divno[$j] == $divtime[$i]) {
                if($type[$j] <> "B") { //set for booking if this header is a doublebook open
                    $flag = 1; // This div is a header
                    break;
                 }
             }
        }
        if($flag == 0) { // link to client lookup or Options base on whether header or body
            $link = 'appt_book_new.php?apdate='.$yyyymmdd.'&aptime='.$divtime[$i];
        } else {
            $link = 'appt_options.php?recno='.$recno[$j];
        }
        echo '<tr>';
            if($i== $timecnt-1) { // user rounded corners if top time division
                echo '<td class="tmspace">&nbsp;</td><td><div class="timedetail_rnd"><a href="'.$link.'" class="fill-div">'.$timetext[$i].'</a></div></td>';
                $rnddiv = $i;
            } else {
                echo '<td class="tmspace">&nbsp;</td><td><div class="timedetail"><a href="'.$link.'" class="fill-div">'.$timetext[$i].'</a></div></td>';
            }
        echo '</tr>';
    }
echo '</table>';
//create the appointment boxes                              
echo '<table align="left" border="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td>';
    $ht = ($cell_ht*$timecnt)-2; // this is height of Time column above. Subtract bottom border
    $wd = screen_useable_width(120, 600); // based on screen size of device being used
    echo '<div class="white_background" style="position: relative">'; //Containing Block
        $cnt = scale_5min($timecnt, $viewflag); // User may scale time division in 5, 10, 15 20, 30 and 60 minute intervals
        for($j=0; $j<$timecnt; $j++) { // create underlining blank spaces which can be clicked to begin booking process. The will be covered up by existing appointments.
            $topoffset = ($j * ($cell_ht-2))-1; 
            $boxht = ($cell_ht-2) -2;   
            $left = 0;
            echo '<div class="boxborder white_background" style="width:'.$wd.'px;height:'.$boxht.'px;position:absolute;top:'.$topoffset.'px;left:'.$left.'px"><a href="appt_book_new.php?apdate='.$yyyymmdd.'&aptime='.$divtime[$j].'" class="fill-div"><div class="appt_client_sv">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div></a></div>';
        }
        for($i = 0; $i<$drawcnt; $i++) { // Now draw previously booked appointments
            $topoffset = (scale_len(($divno[$i] - $startdiv), $viewflag) * ($cell_ht-2))-1;
            $wd = screen_useable_width(120, 600)-1; // width depending on device used
            $boxht = ($cell_ht-2)* scale_len($length[$i],$viewflag) -2;
            $sv = strtoupper(service_name($svno[$i]));
            if($clientno[$i] > 0) {
                $clname = client_name($clientno[$i]).",";
            } else {
                $clname = "";   
            }
            $left = 0;
            if($layer[$i] > 1) { // offset if appointment overlaps another
                $wd = $wd - (($layer[$i]-1)*50);
                $left = ($layer[$i]-1)*50;  
            }
            if($type[$i] == "F") { 
                $sv = "Finish"; 
            } else {
                if(($type[$i] <> "D") && ($type[$i] <> "D") && ($type[$i] <> "K")) {
                    $income = $income + service_price($svno[$i]);
                }
            }
            if($type[$i] == "B") {
                echo '<div class="boxborder svcolord'.$gpno[$i].'" style=width:'.$wd.'px;height:'.$boxht.'px;position:absolute;top:'.$topoffset.'px;left:'.$left.'px"><div class="appt_client_sv"><strong>'.strtoupper($clname).' Processing</strong></div></div>'; 
            } else {
                echo '<div class="boxborder svcolor'.$gpno[$i].'" style=width:'.$wd.'px;height:'.$boxht.'px;position:absolute;top:'.$topoffset.'px;left:'.$left.'px;z-index: 10000"><a href="appt_options.php?recno='.$recno[$i].'" class="fill-div"><div class="appt_client_sv"><strong>'.strtoupper($clname).' '.$sv.'</strong></div></a></div>';
            }
        }
    echo '</div>';
echo '</div></td></tr></table>';
echo '</div>';
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: How about posting some code here so we can see what you're doing?

Comment: Setting z-index: 10000 did not shed any light.

Answer (score 0):

- Inspect the structure of the DOM, z-index, low opacity elements etc.
- Is there any event handler bound to the scroll event of the page that    might be causing the layout to be updated.
- As a debugging exercise try attaching a click handler to the document that logs the target element to the console. Click your div and see what element is reported as getting the click.

*Add something like this to the end of your document or execute it in the console.*

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(event){ console.log(event.target); });
```

Comment: I have added the code for the section in question.  There is no event handler attached to the scroll. It is simple there to allow the appointment calendar to fit on the page if it is longer than the actual screen height of the device. I will try your debugging suggestion.  Thank you for your help.